# Presence validation fails on Heroku even though it works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Since I'm learning both how to use Heroku and coding on Rails I wanted ask this weird problem I came across with

I'm using Heroku in order to push my rails app online and using **postgresql** as my database.
I've successfully pushed my code via command

```
git push heroku master
```

However even though I've added the presence validation to my model, and even though it works online I still cannot get it to work on Heroku. My model code;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, :presence => true 
end
```

I would appreciate if I could get some thoughts. I hope it is not related with the deployment because it works online just fine.

Comment: The code looks fine, can you log into a Heroku Rails console and see if the validation is working there?

    u = User.new
    u.valid?
    u.errors

Comment: @Beerlington u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: irb(main):004:0> u.valid?
=> true

Comment: Doesn't look like the code change made it to Heroku. Are you sure it's been committed to the master branch?

Comment: I've created a new application and added the validation before I deployed the code. Another quick question regarding this; assume that I deploy the rails app without having any validators. later on I add the validation to the models/user.rb and use **git push heroku master**. Would it be enough?

Comment: As long as you commit it to master before pushing to heroku, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify that your master has been pushed by doing a `git diff heroku/master`.  If you've committed and deployed everything properly, this should show no changes.